# How do i convert this to XML layout format?

Tags: java, android, xcode, eclipse, layout

This is the code comming from the Activity file. I would like to have the layout looks the same but i want that code in XML format. Because it's so damn disturbing to have some code in dynamically and some in XML files. So please can someone make this from  dynamically to xml layout?

```
    protected void initLayout() {

    // root view - GRN
    LinearLayout rootView = new LinearLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    rootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    this.mText = new TextView(this.getApplicationContext());
    this.mText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    rootView.addView(this.mText);

    this.eventLayout = new LinearLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    this.eventLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ScrollView sv_obj = new ScrollView(this.getApplicationContext());
    sv_obj.addView(this.eventLayout);
    rootView.addView(sv_obj);
    this.setContentView(rootView);

}
```

Comment: so u want us to code for u ??

Comment: If you or someone could give me some tips on how to make this process i would be very thanksfull.

Comment: @Patrik http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical>
    <TextView android:width="wrap_content  android:height="wrap_content/>
    <ScrollView>
        <LinerLayout android:orientation="vertical> 
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```